# List<>[.] 2 Dimensional Array?

Tags: c#

Currently I'm using this code:

```
    List<Numbers>[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 4500000).Select(n => new List<Numbers>()).ToArray();
```

Now I need to make it

```
    List<Numbers>[,] = what do I do here,  it'll be [39,enumerable.range]
```

if possible?

thanks for any help

Comment: You can have a List of List of things, but not a multidimensional List.

Comment: Your source is going to need another dimension as well; how are you splitting the 4500000 items into X groups? You could use `GroupBy` to identify a grouping key, or use `ToLookup` for a similar outcome. For example you could use a function that groups odd/even numbers together, or some other classification. You can project a sequence into an array of arrays (_jagged arrays_), or a list of arrays, or a list of lists, but not into a n-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

`numbers` is a 2-dimensional array of `List<Number>`.

```
        List<decimal>[,] numbers = new List<decimal>[5, 5];
        for (int i= 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            numbers[i, j] = Enumerable.Range(0, 39).Select(i => (decimal)i).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
List<Numbers>[][] numbers = new List<Numbers>[39][];
for (int i = 0; i < 39; i++)
    numbers[i] = Enumerable.Range(1, YOURNUMBER).Select(n => new List<Numbers>()).ToArray();
```